# Detect failures when running bcp command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to archive old data from my DB to csv files using bcp.
For that, I wrote a set of two Stored Procedures.
One that retrives data in comma seperated format, and the other one that calls that procedure within a bcp command.
The bcp code is:

```
select @sql = 'bcp "exec ' + DB_NAME() + '..uspExport '" queryout c:\bcp\' +
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),@StartDate,112) + '_' +
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),@EndDate,112) + '.csv -c -T -C RAW  -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

This works well on my tests.
What I would like to do is export once in a month old data to csv files and then delete it from the database.
My concern is that there will be some kind of failure in the bcp export that will cause some/all of the data not to be exported and that the deletion will occur anyway even if the old data was not archived.
Is there a way to check that the bcp command executed correctly and that all of the required data was exported properly?

Comment: Reimport the data and compare it to the original.  It's easier to make sure it went right than to guess all the ways it could go wrong.

Comment: Using csv as an archive seems like a bad idea. Move the data to another table or database if you really need to remove it. Much easier to control integrity and access data again if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this now, but if memory serves, I once saw something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (value VARCHAR(MAX));

@sql = 'bcp "exec ' + DB_NAME() + '..uspExport '" queryout c:\bcp\' +
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),@StartDate,112) + '_' +
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),@EndDate,112) + '.csv -c -T -C RAW  -S' + @@servername;

insert #Results(value)
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Then you can query the #Results table to see if there was a failure.